# How can I set manage=False for django simple history table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-simple-history

I'm using `django-simple-history` for my model.  I am deleting a field on the model but setting the `meta` property `managed` to `False`.  However, this does not translate to the simple history table.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass the `HistoricalRecords` class, and override the `get_meta_options` function. For example:

```
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

class UnmanagedHistoricalRecords(HistoricalRecords):

    def get_meta_options(self, model):
        result = super().get_meta_options(model)
        result['managed'] = False
        return result
```

Then we can use our `UnmanagedHistoricalRecords` class in our model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # …

    objects = UnmanagedHistoricalRecords()
```

Here we thus will pass a `managed = False` to the model that will be constructed by the `UnmanagedHistoricalRecords` object manager.